# What does %i and 'ab' mean in this code in Python?

Tags: python

What does %i and ab means in context of the code `open('vals%d.dat' % i, 'ab')` in python

Comment: `i` in an integer variable, substituted in for the %d, e.g. if `i = 3` . 'vals3.dat'. The 'ab' is the mode for open, i.e. append to binary

Comment: "ab" is mode and the content of the variable ``i`` is inserted instead of ``%d`` in the file name.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/ and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

Comment: If this open is called inside a loop, 'i' is probably a numeric variable that changes e.g vals1.dat,vals2.dat. and 'ab' means append binary.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `vals%d.dat` will be completed by the variables after the `%`, in this case: `i`.
The `%d` is a placeholder for digits which will be replaced by the string representation of `i`.

A more general formula is:

'your %s string %d goes %06.2f here' % ('_', 2, 3.141)

%s replaces strings

%d integers

%f floats, which can be modified to be something like:

`%a0.bf` where a is the number of places the string representation of the float should have(including the decimal point), the zero after `a` means left padded with zeros, and b is the number of decimal places after the point.

Answer (score 0):

- % i is used for replacing the %d in 'vals%d.dat' with the value of i (it is supposed to be an integer). If value of i is 10, you would get 'vals10.dat'
- 'ab' describes the modes the file 'valsXX.dat' file will be opened:

  - a: open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
  - b: binary mode

Your code snippet will open a file named valsXX.dat (being XX the value for variable i) for writing, appending new contents.

See the following references:

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

here's the explanation of the [open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

In general `%i` is a formatter that means formatting as integer, `'ab'` is a mode instruction to open that means append and binary. You can find all the modes in the link